# Execution Timeline - Salesforce Performance Analysis

Tags: apex, developer-console

I'm doing some performance analysis of our code.  I'm noticing some gray areas between code execution.  Can someone explain to me why there is a period of time where no code is executing?  What's the delay?  Is it a record lock issue? Or is it just latency where nothing is happening?

[image: Timeline overview of code execution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profiling work on the log that is generated. If you have not right log level then that info will be missing from your generated log. And so you will see holes in your graph.

So the idea is you should set the log level to Max.

More info at : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Guide_to_Application_Performance_Profiling_in_Force.com

Comment: Let me try increasing the logging level on all aspects and see what happens.

Comment: I set all the logging levels to Finest and this is what I get.  There is less of gap, but there are still some gaps, albeit much smaller.  Thanks!  https://www.dropbox.com/s/gss7liplolsqn9v/Screenshot%202016-04-21%2015.00.40.png?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

You have to remember that Salesforce has a multi-tenant architecture and you're sharing resources, including CPU time with all the other users and Orgs in your Pod. That means there will be times when your execution context may need to wait for CPU availability for it to continue processing your request, especially when it shifts from one operation to another.

As an example, where your largest gray area is located, you've just finished running validation code and then have to wait for access to the database to continue the execution context. That creates a pause in CPU usage and the time gap you're seeing.

You don't have the same kind of multithreading in a Pod that operates exactly like the current versions of NT-based Windows. Instead, because of the many different orgs and requests, it's closer to multi-tasking like with the early versions of Windows (Win 95 & prior that sat on top of DOS) where the CPU runs a chunk of code from execution context then switches to another waiting chunk for execution that may not be yours. That can happen because your next operation isn't ready for the CPU to process. That's especially the case when accessing the database or running queries.

Comment: I dont think the gap showed in OP is due to the fact that resource(CUP/ DB) is being used for some other orgs processing. As per my understanding it is just missing log.

Comment: Pods slow down and execution times can vary by large amounts at times when a pod is heavily loaded. That doesn't happen because the queue to start your execution is lengthy, instead because it gets interrupted by other processes. Look at the gaps in the timeline in the early part of the link you referenced where the green blocks don't fill the time increments. Those would have grey blocks in-between if shorter intervals were specified.

Comment: I don't believe Its not that complicated. When it start processing it record time for ex: 12:00:00:001 am and when its stop its record again in log. for ex 12:00:00:010 when it shows graph it use this info. now If there is load or its taking long time it doesnt matter. profiling dont take that into confederation.  I have done and used it many time. Please try on your dev org with min, agv, max log level. you will see want i am trying to say.

Comment: I've tried this with the finest log levels possible, and I still get 'large grey blocks' in which seemingly nothing happens. As I can't find a clear explanation in documentation, the suggestion of @crmprogdev makes sense.